# Unable to display a table properties through Jquery UI Autocomplete

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui

This is my controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
        string commString = "";

        public HomeController()
        {
            FWUtility.connString = "Data Source = DEVELOPER1; Initial Catalog = FR8DemoDB; uid=sa; pwd=123;";
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult FillAutoComplete()
        {
            commString = "select BrandID, BrandName from BrandMaster order by BrandName";
            List<BrandMaster> listBrandMaster = FWUtility.GetList<BrandMaster>(FWUtility.GetDataTable(commString));
            return Json(listBrandMaster, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }

    public class BrandMaster
    {
        public string BrandID { get; set; }
        public string BrandName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my view.

```
@using System.Data;
@using JqueryUiAutoCompleteOnClickDisplayBrandIdOfBrandName.Controllers;
@model string
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Home/FillAutoComplete',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

                $("#tags").autocomplete({
                    source: eval(data)
                });

            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
    <div>
        <input id="tags">
    </div>
</body>
```

Auto-complete is getting displayed but the values from the "**BrandMaster**" table "**BrandNames**" is not showing.

I am trying but it is not happening. Please help.

This is my only query.stack-overflow displaying to write something more so I added this last line.

Comment: Why do you have `$("#tags").autocomplete({});` inside you ajax function? - need to remove that. You also making an ajax call but not doing anything with the returned data (i.e. in the `success` call back). And what is `FWUtility()` and why are you not using `return Json(listBrandMaster, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`?

Comment: Perhaps you need to look at the 'view source' of this demo.

Comment: "FWUtility" is a dll, which has been made by my Faculty to use in this project that we have to write less code. Some methods are there inside this file sir. Can you please edit my code and show me here sir?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, well i have made some changes. Its showing 142 values. But when i am typing some letter then its only showing rows. Values still are not coming.

Comment: Did you look at the source code in the demo to understand how to make a jquery autocomplete work correctly? Currently all your doing is loading everything when the page is first loaded

Comment: No you have gone an changed your original question making my comments pointless.

Comment: Roll back you edits (to the original code), then append the new code you tried.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80447/discussion-between-amit-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/639578/jQuery-Autocomplete-MVC-and-WebAPI) gives a complete example of how to implement a jquery autocomplete